# Avoiding Loops in Setting Cells in Various Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I can set a specific cell in multiple worksheets to the same value without using a loop with something like:

```
Sub ThisWorks()
    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""x"""
End Sub
```

Running the macro above places the same value in all the **B9s** in the worksheets included in the *Array()*

I am trying to do the same thing by creating and using the *Object* equivalent to the above code:

```
Sub ThisPartiallyWorks()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3"))
    obj.Select
    Range("A2").Formula = "=""x"""
End Sub
```

This runs without error, but only one worksheet gets the **="x"** in the desired cell.

What am I doing wrong??

**EDIT#1**

Vasily's Post gave me the clue................this version appears to work:

```
Sub Finally()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3"))
    obj.Select
    obj(1).Activate
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""x"""
End Sub
```

*Although this seems to violate the notion that **Select** can be avoided.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand this is not exactly what you want, but as one of the options for reducing the coding.

```
Sub test()
    Dim obj As Object, i&
    Set obj = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3"))
    For i = 1 To obj.Count: obj(i).[B9].Formula = "=""x""": Next
End Sub
```

> **EDIT#1**

might look like this

```
Sub Finally()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3"))
    obj.Select: obj(1).[B9].Activate: ActiveCell.Formula = "=""x"""
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting `obj` performance, +1 for teaching me something new

Comment: Thank you....while this is not exactly what I want, at least you have shown me one way to use this type of object...... **(+1)**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, Oh I see, now I learned something new, thanks, another +1 from my side ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of using complex arrays,  when you specifically know only two sheets need to be edited. Then we can do in simple.
```

Sub ThisWorks()

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").select
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""x""" 
    Sheets("Sheet3").select
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""x"""
End Sub
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.